# Test sending of mqseries messages without installing WebSphere MQ

Tags: testing, ibm-mq

Is there any environment to test sending of mqseries messages without installing WebSphere MQ?
We are developing some application which will be cooperate with WebSphere MQ system and we are wondering how to test it without buying one. We just want to know whether we send are messages correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that simulates a QMgr.  On the other hand, there are options for development using WebSphere MQ at low or no cost.

- There is a free 90-day trial [here](http://ibm.co/cRYn6h).
- You can run an [Amazon Machine Image](http://aws.amazon.com/amis/IBM/2614) on which the IBM licenses are free for development use. (You still pay Amazon for the image usage, just not for the IBM licensing.)
- If your company owns a current license and support of WebSphere Message Broker, you are entitled to put all of it's components, including WebSphere MQ, onto all developer desktops in your organization as described in the Infocenter [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bh25920_.htm).
- If you are developing software for resale, you can register as an IBM Business partner and gain access to WebSphere, Rational, Tivoli and InfoSphere software through the [Software Access Catalog](https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/isv/sac) offering for $795 a year. That's *per enterprise*, not per person, by the way.
- If your company is an IBM Business Partner and is planning to obtain IBM certification for many developers, the [Value Plan Option](https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_vpo_value_package) costs $2k but reimburses up to $6k of testing fees and includes the Software Access Catalog.

I am a product manager for WebSphere MQ so I'm always interested in whether potential users are able to get access to WebSphere products that they need for trial or development purposes. If none of the options here meets your needs, and this goes for anyone reading this post, I'd invite you to contact me directly using the address in my profile.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that we just use the trial version for tests.